# Switch begin and endpoint in profile graph - ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, line, interpolation, elevation, profile

I created a profile graph in ArcGIS Pro. The TIF file that I use to create the profile, via the function "Interpolate Shape", contains the elevation in [Europe](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/digital-elevation-model-of-europe).

The line that I created starts at a mountainous area and ends in a flat area:

[image]

Consequently, the related profile graph is:

[image]

Now I would like to switch the begin- and endpoint so that the profile graph starts (i.e. left part of the graph) at the low elevation and ends (i.e. right part of the graph) at the high elevation.

I suppose I can manually create a line whereby I start drawing the line at the flat area and end at the mountainous area to achieve this, however I am wondering if there is an alternative to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could flip your line using the [**Flip Line**](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/editing/flip-line.htm) tool.

This will edit your line so if you want to keep the original direction you could make a copy of your layer first.